# Index and assign multiple sets of rows at once

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, set, row

I have an imported dataframe `Measurements` that contains many observations from an experiment.

```
Measurements <- data.frame(X = 1:4,
           Data = c(90, 85, 100, 105))
X   Data
1   90          
2   85          
3   100         
4   105
```

I want to add **another column** `Condition` that specifies the treatment group **for each datapoint**. I know which obervation ranges are from which condition (e.g. observations `1:2` are from the control and observations `3:4` are from the experimental group).

I have devised **two solutions** already that give the desired output but **neither are ideal**. First:

```
Measurements["Condition"] <- c(rep("Cont", 2), rep("Exp", 2))
X   Data Condition      
1   90   Cont       
2   85   Cont       
3   100  Exp        
4   105  Exp
```

The benefit of this is it is **one line** of code/one command. But this is not ideal since I need to do math outside separately (e.g. 3:4 = 2 obs, etc) which can be **tricky/unclear/indirect** with larger datasets and more conditions (e.g. 47:83 = ? obs, etc) and would be liable to **perpetuating errors** since a small error in length for an early assignment would also shift the assignment of later groups (e.g. if rep of Cont is mistakenly 1, then Exp gets mistakenly assigned to 2:3 too).

I also thought of assigning like this, which gives the **desired output** too:

```
Measurements[1:2, "Condition"] <- "Cont"
Measurements[3:4, "Condition"] <- "Exp"
X   Data Condition      
1   90   Cont       
2   85   Cont       
3   100  Exp        
4   105  Exp
```

This makes it more **clear/simple/direct** which rows will receive which assignment, but this requires separate assignments and **repetition**. I feel like there should be a way to **"vectorize"** this assignment, which is the **solution** I'm looking for.

I'm having trouble finding complex indexing rules from online. Here is my first intuitive **guess** of how to achieve this:

```
Measurements[c(1:2, 3:4), "Condition"] <- list("Cont", "Exp")

X   Data Condition
1   90   Cont
2   85   Cont       
3   100  Cont       
4   105  Cont
```

But this doesn't work. It seems to combine 1:2 and 3:4 into a single equivalent range (1:4) and assigns only the first condition to this range, which suggests I also need to specify the column again. When I try to specify the column again:

```
Measurements[c(1:2, 3:4), c("Condition", "Condition")] <- list("Cont", "Exp")
X   Data Condition Condition.1    
1   90   Cont      Exp  
2   85   Cont      Exp  
3   100  Cont      Exp  
4   105  Cont      Exp
```

For some reason this creates a second new column (??), and it again seems to combine 1:2 and 3:4 into essentially 1:4. So I think I need to index the **two row ranges** in a way that keeps them **separate** and only specify the column once, but I'm stuck on how to do this. I assume the solution is simple but I can't seem to find an example of what I'm trying to do. Maybe to keep them separate I do have to assign them separately, but I'm hoping there is a way.

Can anyone help? Thank you a ton in advance from an R noobie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a list of observations which belong to each condition you could use `dplyr::case_when` to do a conditional mutate. Depending on how you have this information stored you could use something like the following:

```
library(dplyr)

Measurements <- data.frame(X = 1:4,
                           Data = c(90, 85, 100, 105))

# set which observations belong to each condition
Cont <- 1:2
Exp <- 3:4

Measurements %>%
  mutate(Condition = case_when(
    X %in% Cont ~ "Cont",
    X %in% Exp ~ "Exp"
  ))

# X Data Condition
# 1   90      Cont
# 2   85      Cont
# 3  100       Exp
# 4  105       Exp
```

Note that this **does not** require the observations to be in consecutive rows.

Answer (score 1):

Efficient for larger datasets is to know the data pattern and the data id.

```
Measurements <- data.frame(X = 1:4, Data = c(90, 85, 100, 105))
dat <- c("Cont","Exp")
pattern <- c(1,1,2,2)
```

Or draw pattern from data, e.g. conditional from `Measurements$Data`

```
pattern <- sapply( Measurements$Data >=100, function(x){ if(x){2}else{1} } )
# [1] 1 1 2 2
```

Then you can add the data simply by doing:

```
Measurements$Condition <- dat[pattern]
#  X Data Condition
#1 1   90      Cont
#2 2   85      Cont
#3 3  100       Exp
#4 4  105       Exp
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally see this done with a merge operation. The trick is getting your conditions data into a nice shape.

```
composeConditions <- function(...) {
  conditions <- list(...)
  data.frame(
    X = unname(unlist(conditions)),
    condition = unlist(unname(lapply(
      names(conditions),
      function(x) rep(x, times = length(conditions[x][[1]]))
    )))
  )
}

conditions <- composeConditions(Cont = 1:2, Exp = 3:4)

> conditions

  X condition
1 1      Cont
2 2      Cont
3 3       Exp
4 4       Exp

merge(Measurements, conditions, by = "X")

  X Data condition
1 1   90      Cont
2 2   85      Cont
3 3  100       Exp
4 4  105       Exp
```